# PHP regex issue: cannot find $C

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I'm trying to parse dollar amounts from a text of in mixed French (Canadian) and English. The text is in UTF-8. They use $C to denote currency. For some reason when I use preg_match neither the '$' nor the 'C' can be found. Everything else works fine. Any ideas?

e.g. use 
    `preg_match_all('/\$C/u', $match)`
on **"Thanks for a payment of 46,00 $C"** returns empty.

Comment: Is $match the actual string "Thanks for a payment..."? If not, well you forgot an argument. ;)

Comment: Are you trying to extract the 46,00 or the $C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the regex can't find those characters because they aren't there.  If you initialize the string like this:

```
$source = "Thanks for a payment of 46,00 $C";
```

...(i.e., as a double-quoted string literal), `$C` gets interpreted as a variable name.  Since you never initialized *that* variable, it gets replaced with nothing in the actual string.  You should either use single-quotes to initialize the string, or escape the dollar sign with a backslash like you did in the regex.

By the way, this couldn't be an encoding problem, because (in the example, at least), all the characters are from the ASCII character set.  Whether it was encoded as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or ASCII, the binary representation of the string would be identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\$C/u', 'Thanks for a payment of 46,00 $C', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

works fine for me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $C
        )

)
```

Comment: @netcoder: yes it is. it's telling whamsicore that his question misses some important details.

Comment: @whamsicore: Your example string is plain ASCII. It doesn't contain any characters which need to be encoded in some way.

Comment: If the question misses some important details, how can you answer it? o.O :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
// assuming $text is the input string
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/([0-9,\\.]+)\\s*\\$C/u', $text, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    $price = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $matches[1][0]));
    printf("%.2f\n", $price);
} else {
    printf("No price found\n");
}
```

Just make sure the input string (`$text`) has been properly decoded into an Unicode string. (For example, if it's in UTF-8, use the `utf8_decode` function.)